# Whats wrong with this FQL Multiquery? No results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
{
        "query1": "SELECT aid, cover_pid, name, created FROM album 
            WHERE owner = 166125753465316  AND name != \'Wall Photos\' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3",

        "query2": "SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo 
            WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #query1)  ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5"
}
```

With above in  $queries, and then:

```
$param  =   array(
             'method'    => 'fql.multiquery',
             'queries'     => $queries,
             'callback'  => ''
            );
            $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

            var_dump($fqlResult);
```

returns me an empty array? What have I done wrong?

I would like to grab albums where owner =... , and get 5 photos from each albums.

I can do this with single queries, but then it really takes long time for the page to load!

Comment: may it be that your privacy settings not allow to share your fotos?

Answer (score 1):

IN this case i think you not need multiquery you just change like this

```
SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo 
     WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album  WHERE owner = me()  ORDER BY created DESC )  
     ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
```

you cal also use this GRAPH API

```
me?fields=albums.fields(cover_photo,created_time,photos.limit(5).fields(link))
```

here is link

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dalbums.fields%28cover_photo%2Ccreated_time%2Cphotos.limit%285%29.fields%28link%29%29

Comment: I need the album: aid, name, created, cover_pid too so i do need multiquery ?

Comment: try this link [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=166125753465316%3Ffields%3Dalbums.fields%28cover_photo%2Ccreated_time%2Cphotos.limit%285%29.fields%28link%29%29)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%22query1%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20aid%2C%20cover_pid%2C%20name%2C%20created%20FROM%20album%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%20126197000730223%20AND%20name%20!%3D%20'Wall%20Photos'%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC%20LIMIT%203%22%0A%22query2%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20pid%2C%20src%2C%20src_small%2C%20src_big%2C%20caption%20FROM%20photo%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20aid%20IN%20(SELECT%20aid%20FROM%20%23query1)%20%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC%20LIMIT%205%22

Comment: I tried this FQL also i got same result i think you have to post this one as bug..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this graph api query - 
USER_ID?fields=albums.fields(name,photos.limit(5).fields(id,name),id,cover_photo,created_time) 
This comes from the recently introduced graph api field expansion feature - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this, and substituting `me()` for the ID in your query, it works. When I try to look for your id, 166125753465316, it throws an "[Unsupported get request error](http://graph.facebook.com/166125753465316)". This could be your problem.

I was able to get data using the PAGE_ID in your comment with a valid user or app access token.

A couple of other comments: You should be using `object_id` instead of `aid` and `pid`. These are on track to be deprecated.

Second, this query is going to only return the 5 most recent photos from the three albums you've returned. To get 5 photos each, you'll need to do something like this:

```
{
    "albums": "SELECT object_id, cover_object_id, name, created FROM album 
        WHERE owner = me()  AND type != 'wall' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3",

    "album1": "SELECT object_id, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo 
        WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #albums LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
        ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5",

    "album2": "SELECT object_id, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo 
        WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #albums LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
        ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5",

    "album3": "SELECT object_id, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo 
        WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #albums LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2)
        ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove newline in your query just use spaces as separator.

Try this edited fql

```
{
    "query1": "SELECT aid, cover_pid, name, created FROM album WHERE owner = 166125753465316 AND name != \'Wall Photos\' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3",
    "query2": "SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #query1)  ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5"
}
```